# WPF - Usercontrol height does not size properly

Tags: wpf, user-controls, view, height, datatemplate

I have an issue I cannot figure out.  I hope I can explain things enough.

Basically, I have a usercontrol that I'm looking to use as a sort of in window modal dialog.

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Opacity=".75" Fill="White"/>
    <Border Width="425" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="20,0,20,0" Padding="3">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- First Name -->
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="First Name:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="3"/>
            <!-- Last Name -->
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="Last Name:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="3"/>
            <!-- Address -->
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Address:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Text="{Binding Address}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3"/>
            <!-- City -->
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="City:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding City}" Margin="3"/>
            <!-- State -->
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="State:"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding States}" SelectedValue="{Binding State}" Margin="3"/>
            <!-- Zip Code -->
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Content="Zip Code:"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding ZipCode}" Margin="3"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCustomerCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

I also have a resourcedictionary containing a datatemplate to connect this usercontrol to it's viewmodel.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CreateCustomerViewModel}">
    <view:CreateCustomerView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Finally, in the main window viewmodel, I create an instance of the control's viewmodel, and in the main window view, I am using an itemscontrol and binding it's itemssource property to the instance of the control's viewmodel.

```
        <ItemsControl Height="600" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CreateCustomerViewModel}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

Now, my issue is using the itemscontrol in the main window, I've tried a few different ways, but I cannot get the control to be the height of the window.  I'm not sure if I shouldn't be using an itemscontrol, or what I'm doing wrong.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemsControl is for collections. By default it uses a StackPanel to contain its child elements, which disallows stretching in the stack direction (Vertical by default). For a single item use ContentControl (the base of things like Button and Label) instead:

```
<ContentControl Height="600" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding CreateCustomerViewModel}" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

Put your `ItemsControl` in a `Grid`.

Declare your `ItemsControl` with `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"`.

It shouldn't make any difference because it's the default setting, but declare your `ItemsControl` with `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` and try removing the `Height="600"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither seem to do the trick.  The end result is the same.  The control expands fine for width, but height stays at the height of the control, when I'm really looking for the control to end up in the middle of the window, and the rectangle taking up the entire window.